# A question from calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, power-series

Can we find reals $x,y$ so $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (a_n-x n)=y$?  I used the following lemma for $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} e^{\frac{k}{n^2}}$ from "Exercices de mathématiques: oraux X-ENS (Analyse I)", by Francinou, Gianella, and Nicolas (2014, exercise 4.26):

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $0$, and such that $f(0)=0$. Letting $s_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n f\!\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$ for $n\geq 1$, the limit of the sequence $(s_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is $\frac{f'(0)}{2}$.

Comment: You seem to have changed the question significantly. So you're asking about this specific sequence $\{a_n\}$ and you've removed the $n$. The answer was given to the general question (as previously stated).

Comment: my question is above

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: nice remarks, still waiting for a good answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no: set $a_n = 1/2 + 1/n$ for $n$ even and $a_n = 1/2 + e^{-n}$ for $n$ odd.

PS: très saines lectures, bravo.

Comment: Just be more specific, it would be great for me as a beginner. It would be helpful for me a full solution. Thank you

Comment: $na_n=\begin{cases} n/2+1, & n \text{ even} \\ n/2+ne^{-n}, &  n \text{ odd}\end{cases}$. So we must take $x=1/2$ but then when we subtract, we get $n(a_n-1/2) \to 1$ when $n$ is even and $\to 0$ when $n$ is odd.